# Apple app review отказ по Guideline 4.1 - Design - Copycats

Tags: ios, objective-c, инспекция-кода, apple

Что значит такой отказ по приложению?

> Guideline 4.1 - Design - Copycats
>
> Your app or its metadata appears to contain potentially misleading content. Specifically, your app includes content that resembles http://tk-sad.ru/ without the necessary authorization.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please demonstrate your relationship with any third-party brand owners represented in your app.

Как можно решить?

Comment: Доказать им что это Ваш сайт или партнер.

Comment: Каким образом? Скинул им сертификат руцентра на владение доменом, скинул письмо от клиента, что он владелец и разрешает приложение любые действия с материалами сайта, скрины хостинга, скрины настройка домена. В ответ тишина.... Что конкретно им нужно?

Comment: В таком случае ждать. Может еще скинуть контакты владельца.

Comment: Подал аппеляцию, и скинул документы, заново отправил на проверку

Comment: На каком языке Вы отправили эти все документы? на русском? или переводили на англ? Спасибо

Comment: Сертификат на владения доменом на русском языке. Письмо с разрешением использовать данные с сайта на английском языке, рядом фото загран. паспорта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился:
 1. Предоставили сертификат на владения доменом
 2. Предоставили письмо с разрешением приложению с AppleID получать и использовать данные с сайта, где расположена API.